# Make a personnal header in Bootstrap panel

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, panel

I want to create this in Bootstrap with panel: 
[image]

Do you know, How I can code this? I'm just beginning to learn CSS and your help will help me to improve my knowledge.

Comment: What have you tried? Let us see what code you have until now. We are not here to help you build something from the ground up, we are here to review your code and help you with very specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

My code :

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div class="container-fluid panel-container">
                    <div class="col-xs-2 text-left" style="margin-left: -20px;">
                        <div>
                            <img src="img/categories/mode.jpg" class="" width="35px" height="35px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-6 text-left" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 4px;">
                        <div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-top: -7px;">
                            <p>Valentin MARTIN</p>
                            <p class="espace">Il y a 5 minutes, <span class="fa fa-map-marker">&nbsp;</span>Saint-Patersbourg</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
                        <div style="display: inline-block; position: relative; margin-top: 3px;">
                            <img src="img/logo/share-256.png" width="30px" height="30px">
                        </div>
                        <div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; margin-left: 4px; margin-top: 3px;">
                            <img src="img/logo/coeur.png" width="30px" height="30px">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <img src="img/background.png" style="width: 100%; height:170px; background-size: cover;">
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">

            </div>
        </div>
```

My result : [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUlDx.png)